# Generic `Future` type compatibility with Python <3.9

Tags: python, typing

I want to provide type hinting for my custom executor class. On Python 3.9 and 3.10, Mypy wants to have `Future[T]` as a generic type:

```py
from concurrent.futures import Executor, Future
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class MyExecutor(Executor):
    def submit(self, fn: Callable[..., T], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Future[T]:
        future = Future[T]()
        # ...
```

However, this code is not compatible with Python <3.9 when running the script:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 6, in <module>
    class MyExecutor(Executor):
  File "example.py", line 7, in MyExecutor
    def submit(self, fn: Callable[..., T], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Future[T]:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

How do I write good type hints for such a method in a backwards compatible way? It seems [typing-extensions](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/master/typing_extensions/README.rst) doesn't contain a `Future` type.

(I *can* live with not being able to run Mypy on Python<3.9, but obviously the script itself must be executable in that environment.)

Comment: I did try a conditional type alias: `FutureOfT = Future[T]` on Python >=3.9 and `FutureOfT = Future` on older versions. But using that as the return type, I get `error: Missing type parameters for generic type "FutureOfT"  [type-arg]` from Mypy.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way to annotate generic types that are not subscriptable at runtime is with quotes:

```py
from concurrent.futures import Executor, Future
from typing import Callable, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import ParamSpec

T = TypeVar("T")
P = ParamSpec("P")

class MyExecutor(Executor):
    def submit(self, fn: Callable[P, T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> "Future[T]":
        future: "Future[T]" = Future()
        return future
```

This example is safe at runtime in earlier Python versions. I've also made use of [`ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) to annotate the `Callable` more rigorously.

If you are targetting Python >= 3.7, you can use `from __future__ import annotations` and omit the quotes:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from concurrent.futures import Executor, Future
from typing import Callable, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import ParamSpec

T = TypeVar("T")
P = ParamSpec("P")

class MyExecutor(Executor):
    def submit(self, fn: Callable[P, T], *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> Future[T]:
        future: Future[T] = Future()
        return future
```

Answer (score 0):

The best work-around I've been able to find so far is:

```py
import sys
from concurrent.futures import Executor, Future
from typing import Any, Callable, Generic, TypeVar, cast

T = TypeVar("T")

if sys.version_info < (3, 9):
    class FutureType(Generic[T]):
        def set_exception(self, exc_info: BaseException) -> None:
            ...
        def set_result(self, result: Any) -> None:
            ...
else:
    FutureType = Future

class MyExecutor(Executor):
    def submit(
        self, fn: Callable[..., T], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any
    ) -> FutureType[T]:
        future = cast(FutureType[T], Future())
        # ...
```

This version of the script is runnable on Python <3.9. It doesn't pass on Mypy in such environments, but that's ok in this case.

I do hope there's a cleaner way which is still compatible with Python <3.9.